# In lightSlider, autoplay stops after clicking on thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using these options:

```
$('.lightSlider').lightSlider({
  item:3,
  fourceAutoplay:true,
  slideMargin:0,
  thumbItem:3,
  mode:'lg-fade',
  speed:1500,
  pause:  6000,
  controls: false
})
```

When I click on a thumbnail, the animation goes to the image and then stops. How to make it continue?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/settings.html), there is no `fourceAutoplay` option (typo here?), you should try with `auto`:

```
$('.lightSlider').lightSlider({
  item:3,
  auto: true,
  slideMargin:0,
  thumbItem:3,
  mode:'lg-fade',
  speed:1500,
  pause:  6000,
  controls: false
})
```

Comment: My mistake, I forgot about the [autoplay plugin](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html#lg-autoplay)

Comment: that's another plugin